# Force X axis text on for all facets of a facet_grid plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gtable

I have the same problem as [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913840/force-x-axis-on-both-graphs-in-a-facet-grid-when-x-values-are-the-same): I'd like to make a `facet_grid` plot with a discrete x-axis, and I'd like to have the x-axis labels be written under each facet rather than only underneath the bottom row of facets.  For instance:

```
# Drop some factor levels to make the plot smaller 
diamondSub <- subset(diamonds, (cut=="Ideal" | cut=="Premium") & 
                     (color=="E" | color=="I"))

# Note that scales="free_x" has no practical effect here
ggplot(diamondSub, aes(x=clarity, y=price)) + 
  geom_blank()+ 
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(cut~color, scales="free_x")
```

[image]

However, I'd prefer not to use the solution from that post, which was just to use `facet_wrap` instead of `facet_grid`, because I prefer the way `facet_grid` labels the strip text with one variable on top of the columns, and the other variable on the sides of the rows.

Is there a way to get x-axis labels under each facet, when all the x-axes are actually the same, using `facet_grid`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can insert a copy of the axes inside the gtable,

```
library(gtable)
g <- ggplotGrob(p)
# locate the panels
panels <- grep("panel", g$layout$name)
top <- unique(g$layout$t[panels])
# intersperse a copy of the bottom axes
all <- gtable:::rbind_gtable(gtable:::rbind_gtable(g[seq.int(min(top)), ], 
                                                   g[max(top)+1,], "first"), 
                             g[seq(min(top)+1, nrow(g)),], "first")
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(all)
```

[image]

Comment: I get error while running the line `all <- gtable:::rbind_gtable(gtable:::rbind_gtable(g[1:4],g[7,]),  g[5:9,])`. The error I got is `Error in UseMethod("grid.draw") : 
  no applicable method for 'grid.draw' applied to an object of class "function"`. I believe `p` refers to ggplot object, is that true ?

Comment: yes, p is your ggplot. What do you get with `print(all)`? It should be a `TableGrob (10 x 8) "layout": 16 grobs` etc.

Comment: The error I got now is as follows: `> all <- gtable:::rbind_gtable(gtable:::rbind_gtable(g[1:4],g[7,]),  g[5:7,])
Error in mmm < each : comparison of these types is not implemented`

Comment: I see. That's because I grew tired of this and fixed it in my own version of gtable. Try the updated code.

Comment: It seems to work but the final figure doesn't look like the figure you posted. On my machine the y-axis get overlapped. The final figure looks like this:  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2wzE8.png

Comment: strange,; make sure you don't forget to issue `grid.newpage()` between new plots, otherwise they get drawn on top of each other.

Comment: +1 `grid.newpage()` seems to solve the problem. Thank you. May you you can add `grid.newpage()` on your code.

Comment: Great way to add axes to every facet, however I seem to have lost the y-axis label. Any thought on how to recover that?

Comment: Is this "workaround" still the best solution for this question? Why does not ggplot support the x-axis in all subplots? @mattek

Comment: worked, but only for 2 x 2, what about other arranges... 3x1 3x2 3x3 3x4 3x5

Answer (score 1):

Script can be much simpler by using `cbind.gtable`:

```
library(gtable)
g <- ggplotGrob(p)
# locate the panels
panels <- grep("panel", g$layout$name)
top <- unique(g$layout$t[panels])

# intersperse a copy of the bottom axes
all <- gtable:::cbind.gtable(
    g[seq.int(min(top)), ], 
    g[max(top)+1,],
    g[seq(min(top)+1, nrow(g)),], 
    size = "first")
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(all)
```